# jQuery return false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I iterate through each row.
If the row background color is green and its respective checkboxes with class as linebox are not checked I am supposed to display an error message on click of submit.
But the return false is not working and the form is getting submitted.Though the message is getting displayed.
How do I resolve this?
Below is the code.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#add-All-button', function () {
  $(".rowb").each(function() {                       
    if($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(71, 163, 71)") {
      var ischk = 0;
      var row = $(this);                        
      if (row.find('input[class="linebox"]').is(':checked') ) {
        ischk++;
      }
      if(ischk==0) {
        alert('Every green colored row should have one of the checkboxes checked.');
        return false;
      }
    }                       
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return false in the outer function, returning false in .each will only break the loop. The other you may need to use to stop a form submission is [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) which can be used to stop the browsers default behavior like going to a link or submitting a forming but you'll need to change the event type on your button to match this appropriately. That is to say that the event you should be listening for is submit. Have a look at the fixed up code below for more details.

```
 jQuery(document).on('submit', '#add-All-button', function() {
     var out = true;
     $(".rowb").each(function() {
         if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(71, 163, 71)") {
             var ischk = 0;
             var row = $(this);
             if (row.find('input[class="linebox"]').is(':checked')) {
                 ischk++;
             }
             if (ischk == 0) {
                 alert('Every green colored row should have one of the checkboxes checked.');
                 out = false;
             }
         }
     });
     if (!out) { event.preventDefault(); }
     return out;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Shane! The above code is not working when the condition is true.Its always preventing the form submission.

Comment: You can use event.preventDefault() to stop the form submitting see the edit above

Comment: Try getting the event from the args rather than the global scope like so `jQuery(document).on('submit', '#add-All-button', function(event) {`

Answer (score 7):

You're not returning `false` out of your event handler, just out of your `$.each` callback. If you want to also return `false` out of your handler, you'll need a `return` statement in the handler itself.

For instance, perhaps (see the `***` lines):

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#add-All-button', function() {
    var rv; // *** By default it's `undefined`, which has no special meaning, so that's fine
    $(".rowb").each(function() {
        if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(71, 163, 71)") {
            var ischk = 0;
            var row = $(this);
            if (row.find('input[class="linebox"]').is(':checked')) {
                ischk++;
            }
            if (ischk == 0) {
                alert('Every green colored row should have one of the checkboxes checked.');
                rv = false; // ***
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return rv; // ***
});
```

---

Side note: This comparison is likely to fail in the wild:

```
$(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(71, 163, 71)"
```

Different browsers return color information in different formats, and *don't* return the value in the same format you set it in (necessarily). jQuery doesn't attempt to standardize this. So the value you get back might be `"rgb(71, 163, 71)"`, but it might also be `"rgb(71,163,71)"` or `"rgba(71, 163, 71, 0)"` or `"rgba(71,163,71,0)"` or even `"#47A347"`. Instead of relying on getting back a value in a specific format, you'd probably be better off using a `data-*` attribute or a value tracked via the jQuery `data` function instead.

---

Side note 2: I wouldn't use the `click` event of a button to hook into the form submission process; I'd use the `submit` event of the `form` instead.

Comment: Thanks Crowder!You gave me some really good info.However the above code is not working when the condition is true.Its always preventing the form submission.

Comment: @Viral: It must be something about how you're checking the checkboxes. For one thing, `input[class="linebox"]` is a very fragile selector, if you add a second class to the checkboxes for any reason, it'll fail. The usual way you look for an element with a `linebox` class is `input.linebox`. You'll need to step through the code with the debugger built into your browser to see why `ischk` is always `0`.

Comment: Also, as I recall, .css("background-color") should be .css("backgroundColor") - I believe CSS properties in jQuery use camelCase.

Comment: @Bemisawa - Both work with jQuery. (Actually, both work with `style` as well, if you do them right: `element.style["background-color"] = "green";` and `element.style.backgroundColor = "green";`.) :-)